# e2fsck giving some error

Tags: data-recovery, ext4, superblock, e2fsck

I am playing with LVM and while doing `lvreduce`. I now get this error:

```
[root@localhost raja]# e2fsck -f /dev/vg1/lvol2
e2fsck 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
e2fsck: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
e2fsck: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/vg1/lvol2

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a correct ext2
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You did resize the FS before reducing the lv, right?

Comment: @Mat while reducing the file system I am getting some error with superblocks , thats why I went for e2fsck and stopped.

Comment: Did you run lvreduce already or not?

Comment: No I didnt, I first reduce the filesystem then only I can go for lvreduce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the filesystem is really on that device, running mkfs.ext4 with the same arguments plus a `-n` will give you a list of superblocks that you can use as alternates.  Eg:

`# mkfs.ext4 -n /dev/vg1/lvol2`

...
`Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
        32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208`

Then you can run `e2fsck -b 32768 /dev/vg1/lvol2` or other backup superblock to see if it will fix it.  PS: 32768 is a typical backup block while the other locations depend on the size of the partition.